# When to say "Yehallelu" by Mincha Shabbos Afternoon?

Tags: shabbat, minhag, torah-reading, gabbai, nusach-ari

Chabad starts the Half-Kaddish by Mincha Shabbos afternoon just after Hagbahah and continuing the Kaddish until the Sefer Torah is put back in the Aron.

Since one should not interrupt in the middle of the Kaddish, When does one say "Yehallelu"?

Comment: Why is one allowed to interrupt Kaddish with wrapping and carrying the Torah?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Siddur Rabbeinu Hazakein](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30450&st=&pgnum=349), the Lubavitcher Rebbe would wait until after Kaddish was over, right before Shemoneh Esrei. *However* during the years תש״נ ־ תנש״א / 1990 - 1991 Kaddish would not start until *after* the Sefer Torah was already put back in the Aron, so yehalelu was said before kaddish.

As regards actual practice, every Lubavitcher minyan I've ever been in waits until after kaddish, and says yehalelu right before shemoneh esrei.

Comment: But Sefer Haminhagim -- Minhagei Chabad (at least versions 1967 1982 1993 and 2005) says clearly that Yehalelu is said before putting the Torah away. Moreover, Shulchan Aruch haRav (OC 292:4) is very opposed to saying even one pasuk as an interruption between Kaddish and Shabbat Mincha Amida.

Comment: @DoubleAA Right, I linked to that in my deleted answer below. Problem is, it also says _"In the meantime the Kaddish is recited slowly.."_ which seems to indicate that yehalelu is said _during_ kaddish. This, I've never seen nor heard.

Comment: Doesn't make it not the intended result. Were you around in 1967?

Comment: @DoubleAA Agreed, and no.

Answer (score 1):

I've always seen people saying it right after the end of kaddish, before taking the steps back for the Amidah.

Comment: See my comment to Hod's answer.